# In netsuite suitescript Can I get the results from MR script from Reduce and Map function?

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have sent some Item to MR script and process some operation on them.  I want a detail summary of which passed and which failed with reason in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Till Now my Solution is :

Create a custom Record with two fields `MR_token` and `Result`.

on MR `summarize` Event . Save the details to the the Record.

and in `Client-side` open a `Suitelet` which shows the results in a `sublist`